# Disabling sessions for a single controller has been deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The problem is;

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Pick a unique cookie name to distinguish our session data from others'
  session :session_key => '_simple_blog'
  #session :disabled => true

  private #------------

    def authorize_access
      if !session[:user_id]
        flash[:notice] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to(:controller => 'staff', :action => 'login')
        return false
      end   
    end

end
```

the error message is

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Disabling sessions for a single controller has been deprecated. Sessions are now lazy loaded. So if you don't access them, consider them off. You can still modify the session cookie options with request.session_options.

Can somebody point em in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this error is referring to the `session :disabled => true` line you have commented out? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It has nothing to do with session :disabled => true

Answer (score 6):

You are receiving this warning because you are explicitly loading the session context via the `session` method. You should instead use `request.session_options[:session_key] = 'new_session_key'` from within *an action*, as the framework now lazily loads the context if necessary (as you saw). If you want to do this for all actions, create a method and use `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :setup_session_key

  protected

    def setup_session_key
      # Pick a unique cookie name to distinguish our session data from others'
      request.session_options[:session_key] = '_simple_blog'
    end
end
```

Comment: Above the deprecation warning in the original post, I also got `DEPRECATION WARNING: Giving :session_key to SessionStore is deprecated, please use :key instead.` So after fixing that, you finally end up with `request.session_options[:key] = …`.